# Как настроить Excel Add-In на .NET 4.6.1 под Надежного Издателя?

Tags: c#, .net, com, office, vsto

В Excel устанавливается Add-In, сделанный под .NET 4.6.1. Работает он как COM объект, т.е. нет ни каких vsto файлов.

Что нужно сделать, чтоб он работал без предупреждающих сообщений при включённой опции безопасности *"Все надстройки приложений должны быть подписаны надежным издателем"* 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особенность разработки на .Net для COM является, то что входной точкой в ваш функционал будет не ваша сборка а библиотек `mscoree.dll`. Именно эта dll прописываться в `InprocServer32` и сначала она загружается, а потом подгружается .Net runtime и ваша сборка.
Так вот, в этом случае проверяется подпись `mscoree.dll`, а не вашей сборки. И по понятным причинам мы не можем переподписать `mscoree.dll`.

Чтобы решить задачу придётся самому писать аналог `mscoree.dll` на C++, так называемый COM Shim. И есть уже много практик, которые помогут в этом, например, [Isolating Office Extensions with the COM Shim Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa159894%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).